# Display html data in UITextView or UILabel in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

How to display html data in UITextView or UILabel, There is some method this work, but take a lot of time to load and when scrolling

```
cell.textView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(
            data: comments.commentBody.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
            options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
            documentAttributes: nil,
            error: nil)
```

Comment: so the issue is the loading is slow?

Comment: yes, when scrolling slow down

Comment: are you sure that it's just the attributed string that causes the slowdown?

Comment: here my code snapshot http://i067.radikal.ru/1501/24/4e87f2b9a6b4.png

Comment: u can also cache the generated strings so you don't have to recreate them every time.

Comment: @rakeshbs Can you tell more on how to cache the generated strings?

Answer (score 2):

If the issue is only the slow loading, try to do the network request asynchronously with dispatch_async in a side thread and then update the UI in the main thread (mandatory!)

```
let commentsQueue:dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_queue_create("comments queue", nil)

dispatch_async(commentsQueue, {

    let commentsRequested = NSAttributedString(
        data: comments.commentBody.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
        options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
        documentAttributes: nil,
        error: nil)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
            cell.textView.attributedText = commentsRequested
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a problem with Apple's HTML to `NSAttributedString` API, you can try [`NSAttributedString+HTML`](https://github.com/InfiniteLoopDK/NSAttributedString-Additions-for-HTML/blob/master/Classes/NSAttributedString%2BHTML.m).

Answer (score 0):

Dispatching a block to the main queue is  done from a background queue to signal that some background processing has finished:

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("YourQueueName", 0);

dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
;
    //Do background `enter code here`process like forming attributed string from API parameter..
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //Update UI for textview ...
});
});
```

In this case, we are doing a lengthy calculation on a background queue and need to update our UI when the calculation is complete. Updating UI normally has to be done from the main queue so we 'signal' back to the main queue using a second nested `dispatch_async`.

Comment: @ TFerrell,thanks, updated  the details.It worked for me.